# 'ILoggingBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddNLog' and no extension method 'AddNLog' accepting a first argument of type 'ILoggingBuilder'

Tags: azure, logging, azure-functions, nlog, azure-functions-core-tools

I am trying to configure `NLog` in my `Azure Function` solution, unfortunately I am getting an error as below.

> 'ILoggingBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddNLog' and no
>   accessible extension method 'AddNLog' accepting a first argument of
>   type 'ILoggingBuilder' could be found

Please be noted that I had already installed the `NLog` Nuget package to my project. Here is the code I am using in my `Startup.cs` file.

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using NLog;

    [assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(Adapter.Startup))]
    namespace Adapter {
        public class Startup: FunctionsStartup {
            public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder) {
                builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
                builder.Services.AddLogging(logBuilder = >{
                    logBuilder.AddNLog();
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Have you ever faced this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I was able to solve this issue by installing the `Nuget` package called `NLog.Extensions.Logging`. Please be noted that it has a dependency of `NLog`.

[image]

There was an open issue in [GitHub](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Web/issues/161#issuecomment-321979369), that helped me resolving this issue.

Comment: See also the getting started guides for ASP.NET Core 1/2/3 on the NLog wiki: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki